# ¿Como obtener datos JSON una web externa?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Quiero obtener el valor de un JSON que mando desde otra web externa ejemplo:

Mando esto desde la otra web

text.php

```
 <?php
   echo json_encode(array("texto"=>"ejemplo"));
?>
```

`{"texto":"ejemplo"}`

Y ahora quiero recuperar el valor de texto en mi otra web, como lo haría?

Link : http://aimbotdb.pe.hu/test.php

Comment: Jhosselin, para lograr tu objetivo te basta copiar y pegar el código que te ha dado @amenadiel. Te en cuenta que él lo ha hecho en jQuery porque tú has puesto dicha etiqueta, por lo que se sobreentiende que usas esa librería. Ten en cuenta además, que en lugar de `text.php` debes poner **la URL completa** de la web que envía el JSON; por ejemplo: `http://aimbotdb.pe.hu/test.php`.

Comment: Ejemplos existen:[Ejemplos de JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) o [jQuery getJSON W3C ](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson) :)

Comment: Parece que desde el cliente, al menos, no podrás scrappear dicha web aimbotera porque al parecer están negando las peticiones AJAX entrantes. Así que, te toca hacerlo en PHP ;)

Comment: No sería mejor que edite su pregunta y que agregue el link de donde quiere obtener la información.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía la web no deniega peticiones, es que ese archivo muestra codigo HTML, no es JSON.

Comment: @EnriqueB. ¿Seguro? cambia el `dataType` por html a ver si se obtiene respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Como ya te dijeron, puedes hacerlo por AJAX; sin embargo, te toparás con una restricción de seguridad al ser dominios cruzados y ante la falta de configuración *CORS* en dicho servidor.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://aimbotdb.pe.hu/test.php',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(data => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si haces esa petición y miras la consola del navegador, verás el siguiente mensaje:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://aimbotdb.pe.hu/test.php`. No '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present in the requested resource. Origin 'null' **is therefore no allowed access**.

El mensaje anterior quiere decir que en el servidor **no se ha habilitado CORS**. CORS es simplemente añadir la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` en la respuesta del servidor; de esta manera, "permites" que otros dominios tengan acceso a dicho recurso. En el caso de `XMLHttpRequest` (interface para peticiones AJAX), esta interface sigue [la política del mismo origen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

#### Debes hacer la petición en el backend

Para evitar esta restricción, debes obtener la data en el backend. Un ejemplo en PHP es el siguiente:

```
$json = json_encode(file_get_contents('http://aimbotdb.pe.hu/test.php'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Llámalo por ajax

```
$.ajax ({
  url : 'text.php',
  dataType: 'json'
}).then ((resultado) => {
  console(resultado);
});
```

El resultado contiene lo obtenido de text.php

Comment: Podrías dame mas información, por favor? y Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @amenadiel sobreescribiste mi edición. Tienes un error de typo en `dataType` :)

Comment: El maldito cliente móvil

Comment: jajaja relax ;)

Comment: De hecho quiero jalar el valor  texto de aquí: (http://aimbotdb.pe.hu/test.php)

Comment: Preguntas con bonus no terminan más. Reemplaza la url de prueba por la real.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ek3g49, pero en la consola no me muestra nada...

Comment: No aplica para el link indicado en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Por motivos de seguridad, las peticiones por defecto en jQuery al usar AJAX, no permiten que sea a otros dominios. 
Puedes ocupar JSONP.
Te recomiendo el siguiente artículo:
https://www.funcion13.com/como-realizar-peticiones-ajax-cross-domain-jsonp-jquery/
o también http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682

Documentación: 
https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: Trata de poner mucho enlace en tus respuestas, que si éstos por algún motivo caen, tu respuesta no tendría mucha validez. En su lugar, trata de dar una explicación en tu respuesta añadiendo código si lo ves necesario.

Comment: Podrías complementar tu respuesta con al menos un ejemplo por si los links se rompen.